# Backbone.js Router: hide in page modal instead of going back when back is pushed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js router based application using the default hashchange handler to move between pages.  On one page there is a button that triggers a modal box, which I would like to close if the user presses back, rather then sending the user back a page in history.

I've tried a couple different approaches, but am new to working with hashchange / popstate so am hoping for guidance.

- Adding an additional hashchange listener and trying to prevent the propagation didn't work; both listeners got executed.
- Adding a call to router.navigate("modal") when opening the dialog adds an additional entry to the history stack, which means that going back works correctly, but it causes the original page to route/re-render again not just close the modal.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem here is not necessarily how to hide a modal, but rather how to prevent rendered/unchanged views from re-rendering when routed to.

One way to solve this problem would be to maintain a "currentView" and in the route handler, test against that view to see if work needs to be done for the route.

A similar variable could be kept specifically for the modal view as well, which would always be closed first on routes.

```
// In some scope accessible to the router
var currentView, modalView; // or app.currentView, etc.

// extend your router's `navigate` to always close the modal
navigate: function (fragment, options) {
  modalView && modalView.close(); // or however you close your modal
  Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
  return this;
}

// in your modal route(s)
//
// Disclaimer here: if your modal windows are part of the history,
// their routes should probably also indicate what should be
// rendered *under* the modal, e.g. `/someroute/modal`, etc.
// Otherwise, what happens if a browser steps "back" into a modal
// route via history, or a direct link?  You probably want something
// to render under the modal.
modal: function () {
  modalView = new ModalView(); // or change the modal's content, etc

  // given the above point, you may want to render the view under this
  // modal here:
  this.index(); // for example

  // then continue to show your modal
},

// then in your other routes, for example `index`:
index: function () {
  // test somehow to make sure that the view needs to be rendered
  if (currentView instanceof IndexView) return;

  currentView = new IndexView();
  // continue to render/show the currentView
}
```

Comment: Used a slightly modified version, but targeting the router was the perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: @BradyEmerson is there anyway you can post your modified solution?  I'm running up against the same exact use case.  any help is appreciated. thx